# Нужно расшифровать данные

Tags: шифрование

кто поможет расшифровать написанное

e8d4e43a50ecccc71c7de6c9054967d7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, никто. Судя по всему вы даже алгоритма шифрования не знаете, что очень сильно затруднит расшифровку. Эта строка состоит из 32 исмволов, цифр от 0 до 9 и бкув от a до e. Так что скорее всего это [MD5](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). MD5 - необратимый алгоритм, по зашифрованному (точнее, захешированному, MD5 - алгоритм взятия [хэша](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)) тексту нельзя определить исходный. К тому же, одному хэшу может соответствовать бесконечное количество исходных строк. Поэтому, мой вам совет: забейте. Определить исходную строку вы сможете только полным перебором, а если там ещё и [соль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)) используется - это вообще финиш.